# centering textView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Does someone know why the following code doesn't center the text in the button

but the second one does ?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotItButton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
        android:padding="0dp" />

    <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/gotItText"
        style="@style/textOnBg"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Got it"
        android:textColor="#00bcfe"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

aren't `gravity` in parent and `layout_gravity` in each child are the same

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gotItButton"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
            android:padding="0dp" />

        <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/gotItText"
            style="@style/textOnBg"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Got it"
            android:textColor="#00bcfe"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well, for starters, the first code contains no gravity attributes in the TextView and the second one does. Since you RelativeLayouts width is set to match_parent, how can we know that the text isn't just filling up the entire width anyhow?

Comment: You did not do anything about centering TextView on the first one. `android:gravity="center"` on RelativeLayout is not about your children in it.

Answer (score 7):

`gravity` is inside your button. `layout_gravity` is outside (centers in parent)

So, you don't need gravity in your RelativeLayout, move it in Button.

And remove `layout_gravity` from button, since you use `centerInParent`.

Comment: gravity is inside - so when in RelativeLayout it should effect all its children. no?

Comment: In theory. But for that you'd better use centerInParent (if parent is RelativeLayout) or layout_gravity (if parent is a LinearLayout) on the children. Note that a child can also be another container, so... no problem at all